# Cannot send mail thtrough PHP mailer through Gmail server

Tags: php, email

I am encountering a problem where i cant send mail using my phpmailer() through my gmail server. Can i know whats the problem?

This is my phpmailer code:

```
    if($count){
    echo "<p>New user record has been successfully inserted.</p>\n";
    require_once("PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "";
    $mail->Password = "";
    $mail->SetFrom("testnoreply@gmail.com", 'Gold Fish');
    $mail->Subject = "Registration Successful";
    $mail->Body = "Welcome to Gold Hotel Event. Your registration have been received. It still processing now! Thank you.";
    $mail->AddAddress($userEmail);

    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " .$mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Mail has been sent";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>Insertion failed.</p>\n";
}
```

I am also encountering this problem also:

```
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in
```

Comment: Did you remove your username and password not to disclose them or did you not use them in the first place?

Comment: i think Gmail use port 25

Comment: @ggioffreda actually i remove them because of privacy issue

Comment: @SunilPachlangia i tried its not working

Comment: Change SMTPSecure to ssl in place of tls

Comment: Are you using Charles or a proxy of some kind?

Comment: @ggioffreda i am using XAMPP server

Comment: @SunilPachlangia i tried it the warning was removed but still i have the error `Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.`

Comment: testnoreply@gmail.com is valid or not

Comment: Your username is your.username@gmail.com and not your.username, have you tried that?

Comment: Check with your web hosting provider that port 465 (TCP out) is open, if not ask him to open that port And change port to 465

Comment: yes its an valid gmail account @SunilPachlangia

Answer (score 0):

Did you uncomment the line `extension=php_openssl.dll` in your `php.ini` file. Gmail uses openssl, which the php file needs to recognise.